# Calculating sum and mean in a list pulled from a file

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, vector, iostream

I suppose before even requesting help, I should mention that this one of the various exercises in my Computer Science course to help us further understand how to pull inputs from files and such. Any help is appreciated, whether it's direct "give it all away" answers or pseudocode-type responses. So, here's the prompt.

> Write a C++ program that reads lists from a file and reports the name, size, mean if appropriate, and second largest number if appropriate for each list; and reports the list name and sum of the list with the largest sum. The file to be read consists of:  a file sentinel, a number not equal to any of the list sentinels... then  zero or more of: a list sentinel, a number not equal to any value in this list;   the list name, readable as a C++ STL string; zero or more list values separated by whitespace; the list sentinel then the file sentinel.

It includes an example, and here's what the example shows.

> 31 17.3 FIRST 26.2 -11.2 8.1 17.3 0.0 SECOND 0.0 31

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

> First size is 3, mean is 7.7, second largest value is 8.1.  Second size is 0. First has the largest sum of the list(s) with 23.1.

Sorry, I know it's all sort of confusing. I'm pretty confused myself, but that's a college course for ya. So, anyways, here is what I've got so far!

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // loop once per file 
    // stop if filename string is "end" or "done" 
    while (true) {
        string filename;
        cout << "Enter filename or \"end\" to quit: ";
        cin >> filename;

        if (filename == "end" || filename == "done")
        {
            break;
        } 

        // open the file 
        ifstream infile(filename);
        cout << "Processing " << filename << ", please wait...\n"; 

        // processing just if file is opened 
        if (infile) 
        { 
            // count the number of lists
            int numLists = 0;
            int x =  0;
            infile >> x;

            while (!infile.fail())
            {
                ++numLists; 
                // read one list 
                while (x != 31)
                {
                    infile >> x;
                } 
                infile >> x;
            }

            cout << filename << " contains " << numLists << " lists.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

So, my output is working so far concerning determining how many lists are in each file, however, I've tried several things to get the sum and the mean of the lists, but I just don't know how to store the values per list, per file. I've thought about arrays, or vectors, but I just really don't know. I'd appreciate any help anyone could offer. Please!

Comment: You should use a `std::map`. The key is the name of the list, the value is a struct with the name of the information you wish to hold about each list (size, mean etc.).

Comment: Your code above doesn't seem to work at all. Have you tested it? For a start you don't read the file sentinel. You also don't read or check for any of the list sentinels. You don't read the list names. And finally the file contains floating point values but you code read ints. I don't think it corresponds to the task you been asked to do at all. Before you do anything else you should sort that out.

Comment: The code above is so far from being correct I'm not sure what to think. You don't seem to have read the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to read the lists in the way the questions asks. I have not tested this code, so apologies for any mistakes, but it does correspond to the question.

```
ifstream in(filename);
// read the file sentinel first
double file_sentinel;
in >> file_sentinel;
for (;;)
{
    // read next sentinel
    int sentinel;
    in >> sentinel;
    // if it's a file sentinel then we are done
    if (sentinel == file_sentinel)
        break;
    // it must be a list sentinel so read the list starting with the name
    string name;
    in >> name;
    // start of list processing
    ...
    for (;;)
    {
        // read the next item in the list
        double item;
        in >> item;
        // check if the item is actually the list sentinel, if so the we're done with this list
        if (item == sentinel)
            break;
        // now process list item
        ...
    }
    // now process whole list 
    ...
}
```

There's no error checking (not sure if that is necessary) and I've left some blanks for the processing the question asks you to do. Hopefully it will give you a start.

Comment: I took a year off of programming, which is why such a simple concept was so vastly messed up in my mind. Sorry about that, the code above is pretty wrong now that I think about it. Anyways, one of the main issues I'm having is how I'd go about storing the list items. Should I store them into an array, or a vector, or how should I go about doing that? Because basically, each element needs to be stored so that the mathematical calculations can be done to them (mean, sum, etc) and then the highest sum has to be saved... or something along those lines. I don't know how to go about doing that.

Comment: None of the things you have to calculate (size, mean, sum, 2nd largest) require you to store the entire list in an array or vector. For the sum you just add them up as you go along, for the mean you just divide the sum by the size, etc.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll do my best and report back soon, thanks for helping me through this, @john.